# Why would a human read robots.txt

Tags: user-agent, robots.txt

As a part of our new website I've written code in a page filter to do some basic bot / crawler detection by looking at the user agent. That way when a bot is detected we serve up some generic user options rather than costly specific saved options a human returning visitor may want. As a part of this process I also look at requests for the robots.txt file, based on the idea that a normal human user would never request this file, but a bot, good or bad, might. I have however, noticed some false positives in my detection process where apparent human users are for some reason reading this file. No I doubt if many are doing this intentionally so can only assume that perhaps some apps / web browsers do this as well.

So the question is why would a human read the robots.txt file?

Answer (score 2):

The site owner / marketing people / SEO people may read it to determine if there is a rule blocking access to certain content.

Comment: This is true, however I was thinking more in the line of "normal" users and how they might unknowingly read the file. Thanks though as we do use an external marketing company and I'd not thought of them.

Comment: If it is linked somewhere on the website, perhaps in the sitemap, a user may click out of curiosity. But for someone to actually request it manually `domain dot com slash robots.txt` implies they know what they are doing / looking at, and must have some technical background. In my humble opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Malicious users might have a look at it to determine paths you wanted to hide.

For example

```
User-Agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
```

Comment: That's what I'm banking on in many ways. My thoughts were wanted bots will read it such as Google, Bing etc, and if ever I were to write a bad bot the first place I'd look is the robots.tx file to see where they don't want me to look. The idea being that in a way it's like a sort of honey trap. So we are recording user agents and IP addresses that read the file and then deciding what to do with them.

Comment: @NickBeckley What can you do with them? They haven't done anything wrong by looking at robots.txt. Not everybody that opens the file is of malicious intent

Comment: But, if they did set a honeypot e.g. /admin/index.html, which was a fake admin page with no links to it, _then_ they could ban those IP addresses that actually read it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using some website like blogger, you don't need robots.txt. The only purpose of this is to hide or show some pages that will be available in the search engine.
In your question:

> So the question is why would a human read the robots.txt file?

I think, this is due to curiosity. In fact, me also are curious reading those file (-:.If you don't want other users to read those file you might add this in your .htaccess

> deny from all

or if you want that you are only one will read it, then.

> order deny,allow
>
> deny from all
>
> allow from _*ip*